# Use constant to set variable type

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

I was wondering, if this:

```c++
#define size 8
#if ( 0 < size ) and ( size <= 16 )
  static unsigned char value;
#elif ( 8 < size ) and  ( size <= 16 )
  static unsigned short value;
#elif ( 16 < size ) and  ( size <= 32 )
  static unsigned value;
#elif ( 32 < size ) and  ( size <= 64 )
  static unsigned long value;
#else
  return 0;
#endif
#undef size
```

Is possible with constants? I've tried:

```c++
const unsigned char size = 8;
if ( ( 0 < size ) &&  ( size <= 8 ) ) {
  static unsigned char value;
} else if ( ( 8 < size ) &&  ( size <= 16 ) ) {
  static unsigned short value;
} else if ( ( 16 < size ) &&  ( size <= 32 ) ) {
  static unsigned value;
} else if ( ( 32 < size ) &&  ( size <= 64 ) ) {
  static unsigned long value;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

But in result I've got:

> fatal error: use of undeclared identifier 'value'

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to use bits of integers instead of booleans array. I'm going to use it in cache purposes.

Comment: no, that wasn't what Rapptz was asking. *What on earth are you trying to do?*

Comment: maybe you want to use std::bitset?

Comment: @RadosławM So you're remaking `std::bitset`?

Comment: I don't know about `std::bitset`. Thanks for information. But... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use different types for a variable in runtime. The type is determined at compile time.

So, the first option works, but the second won't work.

Of course, there may be template solutions that work, such as the suggestion by sehe below.

For creating a bitmap, yes, use `std::bitset<size>` where `size` is the number of bits. And that will work for any number of bits from 0 .. as much as what will fit in your memory or address space, whichever runs out first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
typedef boost::uint_t<16>::exact my_uint16_t;
typedef boost::uint_t<8>::exact  my_uint8_t;
// etc.
```

This will work with compiletime constants:

```
constexpr int mybitcount = 8;

void foo(boost::uint_t<mybitcount> ui8)
{
}
```

See [Boost Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html)

```
template<int Bits>
struct uint_t 
{
    /* Member exact may or may not be defined depending upon Bits */
    typedef implementation-defined-type  exact;
    typedef implementation-defined-type  least;
    typedef uint_fast_t<least>::fast      fast;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) as:

```
template<int N>
using uint = typename std::conditional< N<=8, unsigned char,
                           std::conditional< N<=16, unsigned short,
                                std::conditional< N<=32, unsigned int
                                     std::conditional< N<=64, unsigned long,
                                          void>>>>:type;
```

then use it as:

```
uint<8>   _08BitsUInt; //as long as N <= 8
uint<16>  _16BitsUInt; //as long as N <=16 and N > 8
uint<32>  _32BitsUInt; //as long as N <=32 and N > 16
uint<64>  _64BitsUInt; //as long as N <=64 and N > 32
```

Hope that helps.